# 500 Internal server error while accessing google directions API from asp.net mvc website hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am trying to access the google directions web API from my asp.net mvc web application. My issue is that it is possible to access the API while debugging in visual studio, but after hosting the website in IIS the browser is hanging. On debugging in browser, it shows that the google API server doesn't respond and it returns a **500 - Internal server error as follows** :

> Server Error in '/' Application. A connection attempt failed because
>   the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond 216.58.220.10:443 Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond 216.58.220.10:443
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond 216.58.220.10:443]
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) +309
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) +633
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1740
>   BDW.Rotterdam.Common.APIManager.GetAverageTravelTime(String
>   startLocPos, String endLocPos) +196
>   BDW.Rotterdam.Models.DBManager.AddTrajectoryToDB(String userName,
>   Int32 startLocation, Int32 endLocation, String trajectoryName) +3149
>   BDW.Rotterdam.Controllers.MapViewController.AddTrajectory(MapView
>   addtrajectoryobj) +156    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase ,
>   Object[] ) +139
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary 2 parameters) +265
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +35
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
>   +34    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>   +77    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   +371    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
>   +32    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +24
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +22    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +68
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +22    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +22    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +399    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0

**This is the code which calls the google API when the post request is received at controller from the view :**

```
var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/
    json?origin={0}&destination={1}
    &key=API_KEY
    &alternatives=true", 
    Uri.EscapeDataString(startLocPosition), 
    Uri.EscapeDataString(endLocPosition));

WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer parser =
    new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string responseStringData = reader.ReadToEnd();    
RootObject responseData = parser.Deserialize<RootObject>(responseStringData);
```

I tried to use a different API_KEY, but still the issue persists. 
Could you please help me to figure out why the google directions API is causing an internal server error, instead of returning the JSON result in IIS server?

Comment: Probably something wrong with SSL certificates and you cannot establish connection?

Comment: I am able to get the response from google API while debugging in visual studio. But it doesn't work when application is hosted in IIS. @xomena